# Typescript exported type from module is any

Tags: typescript, typeof, hono

I have one Typescript module that exports a complex type created with the `typeof` operator, like below:

```js
// controller/createProfile.ts

import { z } from 'zod';
import { zValidator } from '@hono/zod-validator';

const createProfileBody = z.object({
  id: z.string({
    required_error: 'Id is required.',
  }),
  username: z.string({
    required_error: 'User name is required.',
  }),
  firstname: z.string({
    required_error: 'First name is required',
  }),
  lastname: z.optional(z.string()),
  avatar: z.optional(z.string()),
});

const route = app.post('/', zValidator('json', createProfileBody), async c => {
  ...
});

export type CreateProfileType = typeof route;
```

```js
// types.d.ts
export * from './controller/createProfile';
```

The type of `route` is this complex type:

```js
Hono<{
    Bindings: Binding;
}, Schema<"post", "/", {
    json: {
        lastname?: string | undefined;
        avatar?: string | undefined;
        id: string;
        username: string;
        firstname: string;
    };
}, ReturnType>>
```

It's similar to `tRPC` since it creates the type for the `createProfile` endpoint.
I now want to import the `CreateProfileType` from a different module but its type is always `any` when importing the type.
This is my `tsconfig` for the module that exports the type:

```
{
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["esnext"],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

In my `package.json` of the exporting module I have specified the `types` field to my `types.d.ts` file.

One weird think I have noticed is, when the type of `CreateProfileType` is just a simple `string`, the imported type is not `any` but `string` and it works as expected. So my guess would be that this is somehow linked to exporting a type which is just an alias to a type from a different package in my case `hono`.
Is it possible to export the `typeof route` to make it accessible for different packages?

#### Edit

When I generate a declaration file with `tsc` I get the following output. So somehow the type of the route is lost.

```
export declare const route: any;
export type CreateProfileType = typeof route;
```

What I also noticed is, when I manually specify the type of `route` like below, the exported type is the correct on and not any

```
const route: Hono<
  {
    Bindings: Binding;
  },
  Schema<'post','/',
    {
      json: {
        lastname?: string | undefined;
        avatar?: string | undefined;
        id: string;
        username: string;
        firstname: string;
      };
    },Profile
  >
> = app.post('/', zValidator('json', createProfileBody), async c => {
...
});
```

Comment: What is `app.post` (express?) and what is its documented return type? It's probably `any`, and it's not clear why you'd expect it to be something else.

Comment: It's the entrypoint for a [hono](https://hono.dev) app, also a web framework similar to express. 
The return type is `Hono<{
    Bindings: Binding;
}, Schema<"post", "/", {
    json: {
        lastname?: string | undefined;
        avatar?: string | undefined;
        id: string;
        username: string;
        firstname: string;
    };
}, ReturnType>> ` which infers the request/response types for this endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my question.
The reason the exported type was `any` was because I set the `baseURL` to `src` in my `tsconfig`. After switching to absolute imports the type was correct, I think for some reason typescript was not able to locate the `ReturnType` and `Binding` type that was used by the inferred type of `route`.